# React: How can I watch for property changes of my UseRef variable (UseEffect doesn't work)

Tags: reactjs

I want to **position** a div as **fixed** and calculate **top** & **left** values depending on a **reference**

I thought about using **UseEffect** with **UseRef** and it worked for the initial rendering but doesn't update when any property of the reference changes e.g. due to scrolling.

How can I watch for changes of my reference? Thx!

Here is my code:

```
  const triggerRef = useRef(null)
  const [popupStyles, setPopupStyles] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    if (triggerRef.current) {
      setPopupStyles({
        width: `${triggerRef.current.offsetWidth}px`,
        left: `${triggerRef.current.offsetLeft}px`,
        top: `${triggerRef.current.offsetTop + triggerRef.current.offsetHeight}px`
      })
    }
  }, [triggerRef])

  return (
    <>
      <button ref={triggerRef} onClick={() => setState(!state)}>
        Open Popup
      </button>

      <div className="z-50 fixed" ref={popupRef}>
        {state && (    
            <div style={popupStyles} className="form-input opacity-75">
              Popup content
            </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  )
```

Comment: You can try watch `triggerRef.current`.

Comment: same behaviour .. doesn't detect updates  :-/

Answer (score -2):

Watch the ref element via scroll on page, set the state of the current value and watch the state

Example:

**Init state & ref**

```
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(null);

  const myRef = useRef(null);
```

**Watch ref element on scroll**

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.onscroll = () => {
    const refHtmlElement = myRef?.current;

    if (refHtmlElement) {
      setOffset(refHtmlElement.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    }
  };
}, [myRef]);
```

**Watch updated state**

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('!!! offset: ', offset);
}, [offset]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ref={myRef}>MyRef</div>
```